# How do interpret these bootstrap confidence results

Tags: r, confidence-interval

How do interpret these BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS results
Intervals :
Level Percentile
95% (-0.0697, 0.0702 )
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale

Comment: SO is for questions about programming rather than interpreting data, so this is off-topic as it is. stats.SE is the place to go for questions about statistics and interpretation. However, if you post that, you should supply a lot more detail; what your data is, what your research question is etc, and make sure to read the help centre there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the bootstrapping procedure and the formation of the confidence interval were performed correctly, then it is interpreted in the same way as usual. Thus from a frequentist perspective if the procedure were to be repeated many times, then 95% of those times the computed interval would contain the true parameter value.